# Create new instance of a class, using a string

Tags: c#, xna

I am currently making a game in XNA and I have been trying to find a way to create a class by using a string. I want it to work something like this:

```
string classtype = "DrillTool"; //classtype/classname
InvItem item = new .... ("DrillTool"); //this is where i'm lost!
```

The DrillTool class looks like this:

```
class DrillTool : InvItem

//The constructor is something like this
public DrillTool(string itemName, string spriteName, string storedBatteryPower etc.)
```

So my question is: 
**How do i create a new instance of a class, using a string? And how can i pass in the parameters or "constructor values" to the newly created class**

**Detailes Below here:**

The MyClass class inherits from the InvItem (InventoryItem) class, so that i can keep different classes in the same list, since they all should be items. The items are divided in different classes because i want them to have different abilities/values and commands.

**Another Question: How do i cast a class as its own type/class without any if statements?**

Like this:

```
InvItem drillItem = new DrillTool(etc.);

(Typeof(drillItem))drillItem.valueThatOnlyExistsInDrillToolClass; //?
//I can't access the DrillTool values of drillItem if it has not been "converted".
```

And not this:

```
if (drillItem.GetType() == typeof(DrillTool))
{
    currentItem = (DrillTool)drillItem;
    currentItem.valueThatOnlyExistsInDrillToolClass;
}
else if (etc.) //I am gonna end up with over 20 classes at least.
```

If i am unclear somewhere or if you need more information, then just tell what's needed.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Side-note; downcasting is a code-smell. You should try to determine why you need that so much; and get rid of the casting need.

Comment: Why not make a class that is a general item class. Then you store all information in the class and store the items name and the items type so you do not need to create classes like this ?

Comment: To add to @deathismyfriend 's comment. Your items should be set up so that polymorphism takes care of all the "specific" details. You should *never* care about the specific type.

Comment: Because if i want some items to act differently in the update method, I would have to "if" my way through all kinds of tools i have.

Comment: @MasterXD But you *shouldn't have to do that*! Put a virtual method in the base class, and have all the tools override it. Then just call it from a base class reference!

Comment: @BradleyDotNET How do I do that? Put virtual in InvItem constructor. And then?

Comment: SO doesn't give me enough space to explain polymorphism. Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx and learn about polymorphism and proper OOP design.

Comment: OOP Design? sorry if i sound stupid...

Comment: **O** bject **O** riented **P** rogramming. No problem with being a beginner; but you should learn the right way to do things before messing around with reflection.

Comment: I'll try reading about OOP, thanks so far :D

Answer (score 0):

**If you have to do this, you are probably doing it wrong!**

Ok, that said; you just need an overload of `Activator.CreateInstance` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
Type myType = Type.GetType(typeString);
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(myType, myargs, "MyOtherStringArgs");
```

I don't really understand your second question; this cast will work:

```
DrillTool tool = (DrillTool)obj;
```

Of course, it will throw if the cast is invalid. You need the if statements (using `is` or `typeof`) to avoid those exceptions. You can also use this:

```
DrillTool tool = obj as DrillTool;
```

Which will return `null` if the cast fails.

You *cannot* cast to a "dynamic" type (without using the `dynamic` keyword). This behavior is not supported/allowed in .NET. The reasoning should be obvious; what if the string is different, and the resulting type doesn't have the special property? .NET tries really hard to be type safe, and behavior like this is anything but type-safe.

You seem to be encountering the pain of doing this; which should be an indicator of my first sentence. **You really shouldn't ever do this**. There are a few valid use cases; I sincerely doubt you have one of them.

Comment: can you give an example of how i use the myargs?

Comment: Its an object array, you just pass whatever parameters you want in there. The framework will pick the best constructor for the type based on the types you passed in. I'm not sure what an example would be besides what I posted.

Comment: Ok thx. :D A new problem though nither Type nor InvItem contains a definition for Parse. What do i do XD?

Comment: How do i then cast the obj as a DrillTool without an if statement? InvItem item = (obj.GetType())obj?

Comment: @MasterXD Well you could go farther down the rabbit hole and use `dynamic`; or you could design your system properly. I've programmed professionally in C# for 3 years. I have used `Activator.CreateInstance` *once* (in a plugin system where I couldn't use MEF). I almost *never* downcast. You **can** do it right!